# SwiftUI Drag Gesture Without Updating Subviews

Tags: ios, performance, optimization, swiftui

I have a ScrollView with a list of subview in it. Each subview (they are the same, repeated) have an expensive init(). I have a drag gesture almost identical to the Stocks App "Top Stories" view. When I drag the view it is VERY slow and I can tell it is because each subview is being reinitialized and redrawn.

My question is: Is there a way to implement a drag gesture without updating the entire view state and thus triggering each of my subviews to reinitialize. My subviews only need to reinitialize when the data changes. Not when the UI changes.

Comment: You could try speeding up with metal via `.drawingGroup()`

Comment: You get print statements from their initializers when you drag? Subviews are initialized once.

Comment: @iSpain17 I will give that a try but I believe the issue is that all the data is being reinitialized because the view and view model are being re initialized every time the State changes. When I drag I store the translation value in a State var so therefor the state changes and all the views bound to the state redraw. This seems like the designed behavior of SwiftUI? That part I am not sure about.

Comment: @bsod, yes I get print statements in the init of the subview as I drag.

Comment: Try using StateObject instead of ObservedObject in your view

Comment: @ZacharyIanBlank
Hello! 
Did you find any solution to that? I've stumbled on a similar problem. Views redraw during DragGesture cause huge CPU usage and makes UX unberable (